# javascript accordion menu that clicks once to expand, click twice to link

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

Im trying to get an accordion menu to behave the way I'd like it to, and it wont respond to my vocal pleas for compliance.

I desire to have the behave according to the following rules:

If there is no submenu, go to the link that has been set.

If there is a submenu, expand it, and setup the next step.

If there **IS** a submenu, and it **HAS** been expanded, a click on the heading will go to its respective link.

The accordion part works fine, but the *'once expanded, yet clicked again'* link part does not. Any tips and/or pointers would be most appreciated.

The code i am using is below.

```
function initMenus() {
    $('ul#treeview ul').hide();
    $.each($('ul#treeview'), function(){
        $('#' + this.id + '.expandfirst ul:first').show();
    });
    $('ul#treeview li a').click(
        function() {
            var checkElement = $(this).next();
            var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode.id;
                if($('#' + parent).hasClass('noaccordion')) {
                    $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
                    return false;
                }
                if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                    if($('#' + parent).hasClass('collapsible')) {
                        $('#' + parent + ' ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $('#' + parent + ' ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                checkElement.slideDown('normal');
                return false;
            }
        }
    );
}
$(document).ready(function() {initMenus();});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your click event reaches the end of that function and does NOT return false when you have no sub-items to expand.  The return false stops the href from being visited.

Comment: That was the issue. I changed the 2nd 'return false' to 'return true' and it works. Thanks for taking the time to help.